# php Parse new line from variable

Tags: php, email, line

My code reads the line (email message) from a comma delimited file and sends out the email.  it works well, i used \r\n\ for the new line however when it sends out the mail , the user receivers \r\n\ instead of a new line..

in the emailmessages.csv it would read

```
"from","to","subject","message"
"from@example.com","to@example.com","the subject","message is this new line \r\n endline"
```

PHP: code

```
$filename = "emailmessages.csv";
$csvArray = ImportCSV2Array($filename);

foreach ($csvArray as $row) {
    $to = $row['to'];
    $from = $row['from'];
    $subject = $row['subject'];
    $message = $row['message'];
    $headers  = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1" . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "From: $from" . "\r\n";
    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
}
```

Could the explode command help me (explode $message ?)

Comment: Are you getting some errors?

Comment: Please post the headers variable

Comment: no i get the entire email as exactly as entered from the csv, \r\n\ is not converted in the email

Comment: headers farible is already there

Answer (score 1):

i found the answer

```
$message = str_replace('\r\n', "\r\n", $message);
```

Answer (score 0):

Email rendered as HTML most of times, so use `<br/>` instead of `\r\n`:

```
"from@example.com","to@example.com","the subject","message is this new line <br/> endline"
```

Comment: – Jelmergu  i did that a few hours ago, $message = nl2br($message);
   but user still receives \n\r\ etc in email body

Comment: [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) split a string by delimiter, for example `$array = explode(';','a;b;cd');`. why use it?